# Gas less Transactions

Tags: substrate-node-template, transaction-fees

Hi I am building a solo chain by using the substrate node template but i am stuck here that i wanna change the gas fee to 0 of every transaction that is happening on the chain this chain will be a private chain so there is no issue of security. Can some one tell me that how can i change the gas fee of the chain to zero gas less transactions. I have tried adding the custom fee into weight files but it did not work so can someone help me out to tell me how can i achieve this on a node template of substrate

Answer (score 4):

Weight and Fees are two independant concepts in Substrate. It is entirely possible to use one without the other.

Transaction payments in Substrate are done through a *Signed Extension*; [`ChargeTransactionPayment`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_transaction_payment/struct.ChargeTransactionPayment.html).
Here is an example of how it is configured in the Polkadot runtime [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/17122815648c65db338a66b9449089f027f85353/polkadot/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L1652):

```rust
pub type SignedExtra = (
    ...
    pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>,
);
```

If you want to omit transaction fees, the only thing necessary is to remove the signed extension from the runtime. This entails also un-deploying `pallet-transaction-payment`, since its logic is no longer used.

Note that omitting fee payments will also remove the possibility of prioritizing transactions through a tip.

Comment: hey @Oliver Tale-Yazdi
Is there any other way, without removing the `pallet_transaction_payment` in `SingedExtra`

 I was looking for a place where I could set the gas fees to zero

I have also gone through this [Shawn's answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3589/2985)

Comment: Yea I guess setting the convert function to zero also works. Then there is a pallet in the runtime without any use, so i would remove it.